# Information theory - Expurgation step to go from average error to worst case error in the large error regime

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

Consider a discrete memoryless channel $N$. We use a code to send messages over this channel.

Shannon showed that if we have a code $C$ with a finite number of codewords $|C|$ such that the average error is $\varepsilon$, then we can throw away half the codewords to obtain a code with $|C|/2$ codewords but now, the worst case error is bounded by $2\varepsilon$.

What is the analogous result in the case where the error is large? If I have a code $C$ that achieves an average error of $1-\varepsilon$ for some small $\varepsilon$, then can I throw away some codewords and still bound the worst case error by something meaningful?

Comment: If you throw away codewords, the worst case error can only *decrease*.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus the question is how to construct a code with bounded worst case error given a code with average error $1-\varepsilon$. I do not know the worst case error to begin with, I only know the average error.